# Joint Three Table and sum column value

Tags: mysql, sql

bellow is my data

Order

```
ID         state
1           2
2           1
```

OrderItem

```
orderID    item    qty  price
1           A       1     10
1           B       3     20
2           A       2     10
```

OrderState

```
stateID    name
1          new
2          complete
```

the view i'm after

```
Id    state     total_qty   Total_price
1     complete      4           70
2     new           2           20
```

my query so far

```
   SELECT distinct O.Id, OS.name, SUM(OI.qty) as total_qty, SUM(OI.qty*OI.price) as Total_price
       FROM Order O
       join OrderItem OI ON O.ID = OI.ordeID
       join OrderState OS ON O.state = OS.StateID
       GROUP BY O.ID
```

its keep back error about grouping can't think way to by pass it
Appreciate the help

Comment: Thanks Alon Eitan for the edit, this is my first question in the site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by all columns that you select and don't aggregate with functions like  `sum()`

```
SELECT o.id, 
       os.name as state_name, 
       SUM(oi.qty) as total_qty, 
       SUM(oi.qty * oi.price) as total_price
FROM `order` o
JOIN OrderItem oi ON o.id = oi.orderID
JOIN OrderState os ON o.state = os.StateID
GROUP BY o.id, os.name
```